# Headless Xcode UI testing for a macOS app

Tags: xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, uitest, xctestcase

We're trying to run our tests automatically on a test machine where all the non-UI tests run perfectly well. We have scripts that run the tests on the command line and collect results for analysis.

The test machine (a Mac mini) runs in a headless manner.

For UI tests, however, the test fails to launch the app with an error of the kind,

`t =    83.86s             Assertion Failure: <TestCaseName>: Application '<XCUIApplicationImpl: 0x60400026e300 com.<app-identifier> at <app-name>.app>' failed to activate (current state: Running Background)`

It seems that it's due to the fact that there's no GUI session around when the machine is running headless (macOS calls such a session an Aqua session). We've tried to find a way around this, but haven't made any real progress.

If anyone has any ideas, we'd appreciate.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm apparently running into the same issue with Xcode 10.1 and Mojave. What's weird is that I wasn't encountering this on previous versions of Xcode & OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was able to get around this by disabling the "Require Password" setting in System Preferences > Security & Privacy and not allowing the machine to sleep or start a screen saver. There's no screen attached to the Mac Mini so that's fine.

Comment: This is not an option due to our security policy. We've gone with virtual box.